# Should an empty numeric property in a Laravel model become negative when decremented?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to learn this tutorial
In the 
     `function createReservation()` function:

```
while (strtotime($date) < strtotime($end_dt)) 
{
    $room_calendar = RoomCalendar::where('day','=',$date)
        ->where('room_type_id','=',$room_info['id'])->first();

    $night =  ReservationNight::create();
    $night->day=$date;

    $night->rate=$room_calendar->rate;
    $night->room_type_id=$room_info['id'];
    $night->reservation_id=$reservation->id;

    $room_calendar->availability--;
    $room_calendar->reservations++;

    $room_calendar->save();
    $night->save();

    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

`$room_calendar->availability` doesn't have a default value. So wouldn't it go to negative when it's decremented?

Answer (score 1):

It will go to negative, and also throw error if database column for availability is unsigned integer.

You can solve your issue in query itself.
Within your while loop when you are querying about `$room_calendar`

```
$room_calendar = RoomCalendar::where('day','=',$date)
                 ->where('room_type_id','=',$room_info['id'])
                 ->where('availability','>=',0) 
                 ->first();
```

After that also put a if block in your code to check whether $room_calendar is greater than zero or not.

Something like this

```
if($room_calendar->count())
{
   $night =  ReservationNight::create();
   $night->day=$date;

   $night->rate=$room_calendar->rate;
   $night->room_type_id=$room_info['id'];
   $night->reservation_id=$reservation->id;

   $room_calendar->availability--;
   $room_calendar->reservations++;

   $room_calendar->save();
   $night->save();

   $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

In this way you will not get any room with availability Zero.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even then, wouldn't all the values in the 'availability' field be in negative, no? then where('availability','>=',0)  will not yield any results.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I didn't get you. if the value of availability is negative in your db then it will fetch zero results. By default you should put some value of availability